# Android 8.x. Camera stops working when screen turned Off

Tags: android, android-camera, android-8.1-oreo

This is a simple app that uses AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver to repeatedly take photographs. Deployed a couple of years ago, it has been working fine on Nougat and below. It also works normally on 8.x provided the screen is on.

When the screen is turned off (8.x only) or the device goes to sleep on its own, the basic chat between AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver continues normally (a beep, counter incremented) but the camera fails to take the photo (to SD card). In fact, the app crashes when it calls on the camera.

The problem was first reported when a user upgraded their LG from 7.0 to 8.0. I, having just acquired a Nexus 5 (8.1), can replicate the problem.

[Android 8.0 Behaviour Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) provided no clues. What's up?

Other stuff: compileSdkVersion 26, minSdkVersion 14, targetSdkVersion 26; tried disabling "Battery Optimization" for the app as well as the Camera app -- didn't help; no other camera app running; issue was replicated repeatedly

Here's what was reported on Google Play's Developer Console:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_54018 (LoadedApk.java:1384)
  at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0 (Unknown Source:4)
  at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6710)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:770)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.hardware.Camera.native_autoFocus (Camera.java)
  at android.hardware.Camera.autoFocus (Camera.java:1431)
  at my.package.myActivity.d (myActivity.java:155)
  at my.package.myActivity$8.onReceive (myActivity.java:8)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_54018 (LoadedApk.java:1366)
  at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0 (Unknown Source:4)
  at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6710)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Update (04 Aug): I've just realized that this issue also arises if the app is no longer in the foreground (e.g. Home button pressed).

Also, a PowerManager code change from PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to (deprecated) SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK prevents the device from dropping off to sleep; the app works fine. [This is my current workaround for 8.x phones!]

Comment: Maybe some other applications using camera, like facial recognition. But why would you run camera in stealth mode..?!!

Comment: @GokulNathKP on both phones? And only after the update? That seems a bit thin, it is probably a side effect of some other change in the update.

Comment: "**the camera fails to take the photo (to SD card).**" Does that mean you are able to take the picture but not save it to the SD-Card?

Comment: @Abbas. From the error being trapped, I know it's the camera that's malfunctioning, not the write to SD card.

Comment: Post the stack trace too.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this time, I cannot post a stack trace as the USB-C cord I've ordered has yet to arrive. [Installation of the app onto the device is via an apk posted on Gdrive]

Comment: `android.hardware.camera2` might be the recommended class to use for Oreo (please just remove the tag I've added, in case you insist on using `android.hardware.Camera` class)... a `try/catch` inside the `onReceive()` method might cure this already, because the auto-focus might only be available while in preview-mode (which might not be the case in both of the described situations).

Comment: @Martin. I've love to move to camera2 ... if only I could understand it. onReceive() calls a function that's filled with exception catching; in fact, if I trap the camera error, the app continues running -- it just doesn't take photos; then, when the device is woken up, photos commence normally. Of course, the question remains: why are phones on Nougat and below unaffected? I'm going to look into the preview mode ... thanks.